# Force scons append suffix anyway.

Tags: cross-platform, scons

Normally scons would automatically append suffix, fx the SConstruct

```
 StaticLibrary("foo", ["t.c"])
```

would produce the static library `libfoo.a` or `foo.lib` or whatever the platform fancies, but if the basic name of the library already seem to have an extension this won't happen. fx the SConstruct file

```
 StaticLibrary("foo.bar", ["t.c"])
```

produces `libfoo.bar` (and I guess it would produce `foo.bar` using MS toolchain).

What I would like is it to produce `libfoo.bar.a` using GNU toolchain and `foo.bar.lib` using MS toolchain (and so on). Is there a (simple) way to achieve this?

Note that it won't work to do

```
 StaticLibrary("foo.bar.a", ["t.c"])
```

since it would produce `libfoo.bar.a` as wanted using GNU toolchain, but I'd guess that it would produce `foo.bar.a` with MS toolchain (and not `foo.bar.lib` as I wanted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest workaround that I can think of right now:

```
env = Environment()
env['MYLIB'] = "foo.bar"
t = env.StaticLibrary('${MYLIB}', Glob('*.cpp'))
```

By defining the name of the library as environment variable, you prevent the Builder logic (suffix/src_suffix arguments) from detecting the already existing extension. Later in the processing chain, the name for the target library gets fully expanded, such that the right things happen.